# Can't start Android emulator after installing Windows 10 Anniversary update

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v

I just installed the Windows 10 anniversary update and now I can't start my Android emulators.

Android Studio shows the following message.

```
Android Emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V
```

But as you can see in the following image, Hyper-V is disabled.

[image: Android Studio error]

I already rebooted the machine. I also tried running the following command from an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

No luck.

Tried launching the emulator from a command prompt fails with the following message:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator. Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling HAXM?

Comment: Looks like you are not alone: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/673647

Comment: Mmm... that looks related to my issue.

Comment: Looks like someone posted a workaround in the Intel forum. If you can confirm that it works for you - post the instructions as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Small update: When I try to update HAXM it warns me that v6.0.1 is already installed. Then it tries to update and says that VT-x is not enabled.

I also tried the steps depicted in the intel forum, but Windows won't let me install the inf file because "The third-party inf does not contain digital signature information"

I'll look more into this and report back if I can find anything relevant.

Comment: HAXM reinstall to 6.0.3 fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I checked in another machine and 6.0.3 works okay. I have to use Docker in the original machine so I have to install Hyper-V anyway. I'll mark the only answer as accepted.
Thanks to @MorrisonChang for providing the solution.

Comment: Why does the HAXM say "Not compatible with Windows" in the SDK Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my case is that I had Credential Guard and Virtualization Based Security.

I disabled the mentioned Windows 10 features using [Device Guard and Credential Guard hardware readiness tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337).

Unzip the tool, in a Powershell command go to the folder where you unzipped the tool and type:

```
DG_Readiness_Tool_v2.0.ps1 -Disable
```

After rebooting I was able to reinstall HAXM and start my emulators.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Hyper-V in the services menu (type "Services" in the Search thingy), and also use the Services menu to turn it back on. Even though it may not be necessary I still reboot after doing it this way.

EDIT: And also did you run Command Prompt as Admin?

EDIT2: Reinstall Intel HAXM, as @Morrison_Chang says

Comment: all Hyper-V services are stopped. I already tried rebooting after disabling/uninstalling Hyper-V.

I ran the Command Prompt as Admin.

Still no luck.