# Android Studio thinks that Hyper-V is enabled when it is not

Tags: android, android-emulator, hyper-v, haxm

I had an emulator up and running yesterday, and I rebooted my machine today and was all of a sudden unable to start an emulator. Yes, I've rebooted the machine multiple times. I've tried disabling via the Windows Features box and also using the command line that is suggested. I've even turned Hyper-V back on just to turn it off again. Any ideas?

[image]

From images above, I'm getting "Android Emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V" errors.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? If it's the 3.0.0 preview, perhaps try dropping back to 2.3.3.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm on 2.3.3

Comment: Did you try to set it ON through BIOS?

Comment: Pinging this thread. I am stuck in a similar situation where HyperV has been turned off but Android Studio continues to think it is on. Would appreciate the help. On Android Studio 3.0

Comment: The resolution for me was to disable device guard, I was then able to install the HAXM driver. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983128/cant-start-android-emulator-after-installing-windows-10-anniversary-update