# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Android Emulator is incompatible with Hyper-V

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, hyper-v

I have tried almost all the ways to rectify this error but nothing happened. I am running a Windows 10 Home Single Language machine and on googling it shows that hyper-v is only a feature of windows 10 pro. 
Then how can I get such a error ?!!??

The emulator was running fine for the last few days. Only today has this problem arised.

Even Hyper-v is not showing up in the windows features on or off list.
Even on disabling and rebooting the problem is not solved. 
I just want to run the emulator since I am an Android developer.Please provide to the point help and workarounds.

Thanks.

Screenshot added for reference.

**Error**

[image: This the error screenshot.]

Comment: Did you install "Intel HAXM"?

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983128/cant-start-android-emulator-after-installing-windows-10-anniversary-update

Comment: Follow the first two steps and reboot your machine, the issue will be resolved

Comment: yes I have Intel HAXM installed and I have done all the steps it is suggesting again and again